# Add extra filtering options to SearchView android

Tags: android, filter, searchview

Lately, I decided to switch from my custom SearchBox to the SearchView provided by the Android v7 support library.

However, I was using a custom Button to provide extra filtering options (through a PopupMenu) because the API that provided my app with data has the option to add more parameters to the search query.
I inflated the custom SearchBox with the filter button in place and the whole thing worked properly, only the real material design was missing.

Correct me if I am wrong but I think there is no button or menu to provide extra filtering options.

I've searched Google on how to add a button to the SearchView and the things that I found were just not doing the trick for me.

So my question/problem is, how do I add extra filtering options (preferably with a custom button or at least an option to set the OnClick listener) the proper way without breaking the guidelines?

I have tried to get the LinearLayout from the SearchView with the Identifier android:id/submit_area, using

```
int parentLayoutId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/submit_area", null, null);
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) searchView.findViewById(parentLayoutId);
```

But nothing is found with that Id.
When debugging the app, I can see the ID of the LinearLayout named submit_area (and it's different than the parentLayoutId, but I don't want to hardcode the id into the app).

Am I doing it completely wrong or is it not possible at all?

Note: I've seen how the YouTube app gives you filtering options after you have searched, but that is not really ideal since I've got a limited amount of API requests available every month.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the custom search functionality like you are trying to.

But in general, if you want to cut down on the number of API requests, then your best bet is probably to have the filter given pre-search. (Meaning: ask for the filter beforehand, and then just apply it to the query/request when the it is entered)

In the scenario you are describing my suggestion would be to create a custom actionview where the user can enter the 'filters' before they enter the 'search request' (I haven't tried this at all, but that would be the direction I look in for now)

Making a layout in the 'app bar' similar to the following ascii art...

```
| [SEARCH_??_________] | [Add Filter #] | [...] |
```

I'd probably change the '#' to the number of filters they have active (if you decide to allow more than one) (as a visual cue that they -are- filtering)

https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views.html